# Cascading Combo Box Query for Union Query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010, cascadingdropdown, subform

I've been working on a database to organize a resource of papers for assigned readers to easily access and review in my office.

I've taken to a cascading combo box skeleton from [here](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/combo-boxes/cascading.html), and I am hoping to get the reviewers and assigners to filter the papers down in a subform according to the criteria. The problem has largely been due to the fact that my organization leaves me to have a branched then linear relationship tree as opposed to a straight linear relationship tree. There are a lot of useful tips out there but I just cannot seem to get the correct combination because of this, to resolve my obstacle.

The relationship tree is as follows Paper Type>SubCommittee>Session>Papers. I've settled on this because I am reviewing papers from one source (international resource) that has two paper types (working and informal) and has several subcommittees (my office is only interested in two of the committees).

The cascade works fine, the subform populates initially in a correct manner from a query, but as the options are selected the query is unable to match the criteria as they are lookup values.

The query identified as qrylstpapers contains the following fields:

```
PaperTypeName, SubCommitteeName, SessionNumber, PaperNumber, Title, Subject, Origin.
```

These fields are pulled from the tables PaperType, SubCommittee, Session, Papers

I have two queries, one for Working and one for Informal papertypes. I have a third Union query to combine the two.

I thought, making a query from the union query would make it easier, and while it populates the subform, sorting is not working.

The command I am using in VBA to sort the query of the union query is as follows:

```
Private Sub FilterPaperList()

Dim strRS As String

strRS = "SELECT qrylstpapers.Title, qrylstpapers.PaperTypeName FROM qrylstpapers"

If Not IsNull(Me.cboPaperNumberAssign) Then
    strRS = strRS & " WHERE PaperNumber = " & Me.cboPaperNumberAssign
ElseIf Not IsNull(Me.cboSessionAssign) Then
    strRS = strRS & " WHERE SessionNumber = " & Me.cboSessionAssign
ElseIf Not IsNull(Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign) Then
    strRS = strRS & " WHERE SubCommitteeName = " & Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign
ElseIf Not IsNull(Me.cboPaperTypeAssign) Then
   strRS = strRS & " WHERE PaperTypeName = " & Me.cboPaperTypeAssign
End If

strRS = strRS & " ORDER BY qrylstpapers.Title;"

Me.lstPapers.RowSource = strRS

Me.lstPapers.Requery

End Sub
```

One thing I did try that kind of worked was specify "Me.cboPapertypeAssign.Column(1)" and it would pop up a dialog window asking for input, following with the papertypename "WP" or "INF" would give me the appropriate sorting.

Any thoughts, insight, and/or general criticism would be much appreciated. Even if it's a restructuring of the relationships.

*EDIT*

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cboAgency_AfterUpdate()

  ' Set the Mode combo box to be limited by the selected Agency
  Me.cboMode.RowSource = "SELECT tblMode.ModeID, tblMode.ModeName FROM tblMode " & _
     " WHERE AgencyID = " & Nz(Me.cboAgency) & _
     " ORDER BY ModeName"
  Me.cboMode = Null

    EnableControls


End Sub

Private Sub cboMode_AfterUpdate()
  ' Set the Branch combo box to be limited by the selected Mode
  Me.cboBranch.RowSource = "SELECT tblBranch.BranchID, tblBranch.BranchName FROM tblBranch " & _
     " WHERE ModeID = " & Nz(Me.cboMode) & _
     " ORDER BY BranchName"
  Me.cboBranch = Null

    EnableControls



End Sub

Private Sub cboBranch_AfterUpdate()
  ' Set the Office combo box to be limited by the selected Branch
  Me.cboOffice.RowSource = "SELECT tblOffice.OfficeID, tblOffice.OfficeNumber FROM tblOffice " & _
     " WHERE BranchID = " & Nz(Me.cboBranch) & _
     " ORDER BY OfficeNumber"
  Me.cboOffice = Null

    EnableControls


End Sub


Private Sub cboOffice_AfterUpdate()
  ' Set the Reviewer combo box to be limited by the selected Office
  Me.cboReviewer.RowSource = "SELECT tblReviewers.ReviewerID, tblReviewers.LastName FROM tblReviewers " & _
     " WHERE OfficeID = " & Nz(Me.cboOffice) & _
     " ORDER BY LastName"
  Me.cboReviewer = Null

    EnableControls



End Sub

Private Sub cboPaperTypeAssign_AfterUpdate()
'Enable the SubCommittee Combo Box
If Me.cboPaperTypeAssign.Column(1) = "WP" Then
    Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign.RowSource = "SELECT tblUNWPSubCommittee.SubCommitteeID, tblUNWPSubCommittee.SubCommitteeName From tblUNWPSubCommittee " & _
        " Where PaperTypeID = " & Nz(Me.cboPaperTypeAssign) & _
        " ORDER BY SubCommitteeName"
    Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign = Null
ElseIf Me.cboPaperTypeAssign.Column(1) = "INF" Then
    Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign.RowSource = "SELECT tblUNINFSubCommittee.SubCommitteeID, tblUNINFSubCommittee.SubCommitteeName From tblUNINFSubCommittee " & _
        " Where PaperTypeID = " & Nz(Me.cboPaperTypeAssign) & _
        " ORDER BY SubCommitteeName"
    Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign = Null
End If

    EnableControls
    FilterPaperList

End Sub

Private Sub cboSubCommitteeAssign_AfterUpdate()
'Enable the Session Combo Box
If Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign.Column(1) = "GHS" And Me.cboPaperTypeAssign.Column(1) = "INF" Then
    Me.cboSessionAssign.RowSource = "SELECT tblUNINFSessions.SessionID, tblUNINFSessions.SessionNumber From tblUNINFSessions " & _
        " Where SubCommitteeID = " & Nz(Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign) & _
        " ORDER BY SessionNumber"
    Me.cboSessionAssign = Null
ElseIf Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign.Column(1) = "TDG" And Me.cboPaperTypeAssign.Column(1) = "INF" Then
    Me.cboSessionAssign.RowSource = "SELECT tblUNINFSessions.SessionID, tblUNINFSessions.SessionNumber From tblUNINFSessions " & _
        " Where SubCommitteeID = " & Nz(Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign) & _
        " ORDER BY SessionNumber"
    Me.cboSessionAssign = Null
ElseIf Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign.Column(1) = "GHS" And Me.cboPaperTypeAssign.Column(1) = "WP" Then
    Me.cboSessionAssign.RowSource = "SELECT tblUNWPSessions.SessionID, tblUNWPSessions.SessionNumber From tblUNWPSessions " & _
        " Where SubCommitteeID = " & Nz(Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign) & _
        " ORDER BY SessionNumber"
    Me.cboSessionAssign = Null
ElseIf Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign.Column(1) = "TDG" And Me.cboPaperTypeAssign.Column(1) = "WP" Then
    Me.cboSessionAssign.RowSource = "SELECT tblUNWPSessions.SessionID, tblUNWPSessions.SessionNumber From tblUNWPSessions " & _
        " Where SubCommitteeID = " & Nz(Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign) & _
        " ORDER BY SessionNumber"
    Me.cboSessionAssign = Null
End If

    EnableControls
    FilterPaperList
End Sub

Private Sub cboSessionAssign_AfterUpdate()

'Enable the Paper Number Combo Box
If Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign.Column(1) = "GHS" And Me.cboPaperTypeAssign.Column(1) = "INF" Then
    Me.cboPaperNumberAssign.RowSource = "Select tblUNINFPapers.ID, tblUNINFpapers.PaperNumber From tblUNINFPapers " & _
        " Where SessionID = " & Nz(Me.cboSessionAssign) & _
        " Order by PaperNumber"
ElseIf Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign.Column(1) = "TDG" And Me.cboPaperTypeAssign.Column(1) = "INF" Then
    Me.cboPaperNumberAssign.RowSource = "Select tblUNINFPapers.ID, tblUNINFpapers.PaperNumber From tblUNINFPapers " & _
        " Where SessionID = " & Nz(Me.cboSessionAssign) & _
        " Order by PaperNumber"
ElseIf Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign.Column(1) = "GHS" And Me.cboPaperTypeAssign.Column(1) = "WP" Then
    Me.cboPaperNumberAssign.RowSource = "Select tblUNWPPapers.ID, tblUNWPPapers.PaperNumber From tblUNWPPapers " & _
        " Where SessionID = " & Nz(Me.cboSessionAssign) & _
        " Order by PaperNumber"
ElseIf Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign.Column(1) = "TDG" And Me.cboPaperTypeAssign.Column(1) = "WP" Then
    Me.cboPaperNumberAssign.RowSource = "Select tblUNWPPapers.ID, tblUNWPPapers.PaperNumber From tblUNWPPapers " & _
        " Where SessionID = " & Nz(Me.cboSessionAssign) & _
        " Order by PaperNumber"
End If
    EnableControls
    FilterPaperList
End Sub

Private Sub cboPaperNumberAssign_AfterUpdate()
    ' Filter the list of papers based on the selection(s)
    FilterPaperList
End Sub


Private Sub FilterPaperList()

    Dim strRS As String

'     Filter the list box appropriateley based on the combo box selection(s)
    strRS = "SELECT qrylstpapers.Title, qrylstpapers.PaperTypeName FROM qrylstpapers"

    If Not IsNull(Me.cboPaperNumberAssign) Then
        strRS = strRS & " WHERE PaperNumber = " & Me.cboPaperNumberAssign
    ElseIf Not IsNull(Me.cboSessionAssign) Then
        strRS = strRS & " WHERE SessionNumber = " & Me.cboSessionAssign
    ElseIf Not IsNull(Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign) Then
        strRS = strRS & " WHERE SubCommitteeName = " & Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign
    ElseIf Not IsNull(Me.cboPaperTypeAssign) Then
       strRS = strRS & " WHERE PaperTypeName = " & Me.cboPaperTypeAssign
    End If

    strRS = strRS & " ORDER BY qrylstpapers.Title;"

    Me.lstPapers.RowSource = strRS

    Me.lstPapers.Requery


End Sub


Private Sub EnableControls()

  ' Clear the Reviewer combo boxes
  If IsNull(Me.cboAgency) Then
     Me.cboMode = Null
  End If

  If IsNull(Me.cboMode) Then
    Me.cboBranch = Null
  End If

  If IsNull(Me.cboBranch) Then
    Me.cboOffice = Null
  End If

  If IsNull(Me.cboOffice) Then
    Me.cboReviewer = Null
  End If

' Clear the PaperAssign combo boxes
If IsNull(Me.cboPaperTypeAssign) Then
    Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign = Null
    End If
If IsNull(Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign) Then
    Me.cboSessionAssign = Null
    End If
If IsNull(Me.cboSessionAssign) Then
    Me.cboPaperNumberAssign = Null
    End If

' Enable or disable Reviewer combo boxes based on whether the combo box preceeding it has a value.

  Me.cboMode.Enabled = (Not IsNull(Me.cboAgency))
  Me.cboBranch.Enabled = (Not IsNull(Me.cboMode))
  Me.cboOffice.Enabled = (Not IsNull(Me.cboBranch))
  Me.cboReviewer.Enabled = (Not IsNull(Me.cboOffice))

' Enable or disable PaperAssign combo boxes based on whether the combo box preceeding it has a value.

 Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign.Enabled = (Not IsNull(Me.cboPaperTypeAssign))
 Me.cboSessionAssign.Enabled = (Not IsNull(Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign))
 Me.cboPaperNumberAssign.Enabled = (Not IsNull(Me.cboSessionAssign))

End Sub


Private Sub Form_Load()
    EnableControls
    FilterPaperList
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things stand out in your VBA query:

1. Multiple combo box instances are not included in the logic;
2. String and numeric data may not be fully adhered. Unless SubCommitteeName and PaperTypeName are numeric fields, their expressions need single quotes;

Consider the following to allow any box to be concatenated in `WHERE` statement (notice the seemingly redundant use of the true statement `1 = 1` which is used to begin concatenation. Also, I broke the `ElseIfs` since multiple outcomes should be possible for any combination of combox box selections.

```
Private Sub FilterPaperList()

Dim strRS As String

strRS = "SELECT qrylstpapers.Title, qrylstpapers.PaperTypeName " _
          & " FROM qrylstpapers " _
          & " WHERE 1 = 1 "

If Not IsNull(Me.cboPaperNumberAssign) Then
    strRS = strRS & " AND PaperNumber = " & Me.cboPaperNumberAssign
End if
If Not IsNull(Me.cboSessionAssign) Then
    strRS = strRS & " AND SessionNumber = '" & Me.cboSessionAssign
End If
If Not IsNull(Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign) Then
    strRS = strRS & " AND SubCommitteeName = " & Me.cboSubCommitteeAssign & "'"
End If
If Not IsNull(Me.cboPaperTypeAssign) Then
    strRS = strRS & " AND PaperTypeName = '" & Me.cboPaperTypeAssign & "'"
End If

strRS = strRS & " ORDER BY qrylstpapers.Title;"

Me.lstPapers.RowSource = strRS    
Me.lstPapers.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to post everything, as lengthy as it is, but the code you took the time to write/modify does not resolve my problem. So, I have added everything to my original post.